# C++ Getting the Device Context of Fullscreen Window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx, screenshot

I'm trying to get the device context of a window handler.

`IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(WHandle);`

But I could not get the actual application's handler.It's is getting the Entire Desktop screen.

How to get the device context of a Full screen Application ?

Comment: So it's a *"full screen"* app and your getting a handle to the *"entire desktop"*? Surely that makes sense, doesn't it? Or did I miss something?

Comment: yes. @RogerRowland. i captured a image using that handler. it gives the image of Desktop screen. its not giving the actual full screen application screenshot.Plz give any suggestions.

Comment: You cannot capture the contents of a DirectX application through it's underlying window's DC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (i've no windows 8 to try) this can help. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> GetDC function
>
> The GetDC function retrieves a handle to a device context (DC) for the
>   client area of a specified window or for the entire screen

Comment: I tried GetDC function.As My application is a Game,It always runs in fullscreen mode.but I could not get the handler & device context of that Game application by using GetDC or GetWindowDC.

Comment: Games are not my area. So, not sure, can [this](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/34229.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take a screenshot of your game, you can try DirectX function: [GetFrontBufferData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), be careful, this function is very slow. but, if your game use an Overlay surface, then there is no way to capture it except hooking DirectX.